# Android dynamic buttons and checkbox getting id0x0 on rotate

Tags: android

I found the following Android sample app to create a scrollview with checkbox and buttons, everything work great except when I switch or rotate to landscape mode, it crashes with:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

Does rotating the app caused it use the same ids in the for statement?
can I release the setid (if that is the problem before reassigning)

And how could I save the state of checkbox when I rotate?

Sample Code:

```
package life.poa.webcastman.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ScrollView scrollview;
    Button dynamicbtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //AppCompActivity on public class
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollview = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrollview.addView(linearlayout);

        ImageView imagetop = new ImageView(this);
        imagetop.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher );
        imagetop.setMaxHeight(50);
        imagetop.setMaxWidth(50);
        linearlayout.addView(imagetop);

        for(int i = 0; i<25;i++)
        {
            LinearLayout linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearlayout.addView(linear1);

            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher );
            image.setMaxHeight(50);
            image.setMaxWidth(50);
            linear1.addView(image);

            dynamicbtn = new Button(this);
            dynamicbtn.setText("Button no... "+i);
            dynamicbtn.setId(i);
            dynamicbtn.setTextSize(10);
            dynamicbtn.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
            dynamicbtn.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            dynamicbtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linear1.addView(dynamicbtn);
            dynamicbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yipee.."+ v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            CheckBox dynamicchk = new CheckBox(this);
            dynamicchk.setId(i);
            dynamicchk.setText("Wow..A checkbox" + i);
            linear1.addView(dynamicchk);
            dynamicchk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked.."+ arg0.getId() + " " + arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }

        this.setContentView(scrollview);

    }

}
```

Abend:

```
09-04 18:59:04.631 2854-2854/life.poa.webcastman.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: life.poa.webcastman.myapplication, PID: 2854
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{life.poa.webcastman.myapplication/life.poa.webcastman.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
         at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13764)
         at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3781)
         at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13740)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2893)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2893)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2893)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2893)
         at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:13718)
         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2009)
         at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1023)
         at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:978)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1162)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Each time through the loop, you're setting the same ID on a `Button` and a `Checkbox`, which is why you're getting that Exception. If you want to keep your current setup, you could try setting the `Button`s' IDs to `2*i`, and the `CheckBox`es' to `2*i+1`. Or you might investigate using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `ID`. If You want to assign some `ID` to the view you could achive this by using `view.setTag()`. And it will not affect any aspect of view hierarchy:

```
...
dynamicbtn.setTag(i);
...
dynamicbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
        //You can cast it to `Integer` to get `ID` value
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yipee.."+ v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
});
... 
dynamicchk.setTag(i);
...
dynamicchk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1)
    {    
         //You can cast it to `Integer` to get `ID` value
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked.."+ arg0.getTag() + " " + arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome answer works like a charm... Do you know how I would create an array to store what was click, since it loses what was clicked after rotating.

Comment: Do you want to save clicks on buttons and check boxes separately or just save clicks by certain `ID`?